# How to set colours to corresponding values

Tags: r

The distribution of colours should be according to values.

Example:

```
colour.palette <- colorRampPalette(c("darkgreen","yellow","red"), space = "rgb")

par(mfrow=c(1,2))
x1 <- c(0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.65,0.70,0.725,0.750,0.775,0.80,0.825,0.85,0.875,0.9,1)
x2 <- c(0.01,0.02,0.03,0.04,0.05,0.06,0.065,0.070,0.225,0.350,0.475,0.50)
barplot(as.matrix(x1), horiz=FALSE, col=colour.palette(length(x1)))
barplot(as.matrix(x2), horiz=FALSE, col=colour.palette(length(x2)))
```

[image]

The barplot for `x2` colours distribution should be up to yellow and not red. Values corresponding to `red` colour are values approx. from 0.8 up to 1.

So how to modify this example that would take any vector length and plot colours that would match the 0-1 interval? **There could be also up to 150 data points in 0-1 interval**. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is definitely an easier way but what you can do is to bin your data and create matching factor labels. I used your data.

```
# binning
x1b <- .bincode(x1,seq(0,1,0.1),T)
x2b <- .bincode(x2,seq(0,1,0.1),T)
# which "factor levels" also appear in the second vector?
a <- intersect(x2b,x1b)
# set factor labels
x1bf <- factor(x1b, labels = colour.palette(length(seq(0,1,0.1))-1))
x2bf <- factor(x2b, labels = colour.palette(length(seq(0,1,0.1))-1)[a])
# plot
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
barplot(as.matrix(x1), horiz=FALSE, col=as.character(x1bf))
barplot(as.matrix(x2), horiz=FALSE, col=as.character(x2bf))
```

or use the length of the longer vector

```
x1b <- .bincode(x1,seq(0,1,1/length(x1)),T)
x2b <- .bincode(x2,seq(0,1,1/length(x1)),T)
x1bf <- factor(x1b, labels = colour.palette(length(x1))[unique(x1b)])
x2bf <- factor(x2b, labels = colour.palette(length(x1))[unique(x2b)])
```